# More info about reason for JavaScript Image onerror

Tags: javascript, php, image

I am constructing an Image in JavaScript to load an image, including providing an onerror function in case something goes wrong.  In that case, I would like more information about the cause of the error, e.g., is the image missing, or was there a network problem, security restriction,...

Server-side, I am not just serving static images, I am actually using PHP to do some checks first.  Ideally, I would like my server to send an image if it can, but if not, provide some kind of custom text message.

The onerror() function does not seem to provide any extra information, other than firing or not. I can ask the server for more info in a separate call, but my code would be much simpler if it could access the information already sent and received.

Can I get more information (ANY information) about the reason for onerror() firing?  Can I send a custom error message from PHP that JavaScript can access?

Comment: if your code is expecting an image, sending some text or html is just going to be itself treated as an error. e.g it'd be like trying to do `<img src="foo.html" />` and wondering why you got a broken image icon instead of the document inside the .html file.

Comment: The `onerror` method only has one argument, the `event` and that does not contain any of the information you're asking for

Comment: One way to at least tell the (normally-abled) user what went wrong could be to deliver an alternative image that _contains_ an error message in the form of “text” in the image. // Apart from that, could you be more specific as to what kind of errors you expect to see? “Network problems” should not be a case to be concerned about IMHO (or if there are network problems, they will likely affect more than just that one image). […]

Comment: […] And if “security restrictions” means restrictions implemented by your system, you could handle those plus the case of “image not found” by doing an AJAX request for the image URL first – that you can answer with a text error message/an error code, that your script can react to. If no error is indicated, then make the same request again using an `Image` object (you might want to think about HTTP caching in this case; or make the AJAX request a HEAD request only instead of a full GET).

Comment: I expect to see network problems on a regular basis because I expect my app to be off-line most of the time.  It is not a problem if many images are affected, because it's not my "fault" that the user went off line, but JavaScript needs to know this, as opposed to a problem at the server.

Comment: If adeneo is correct, then I am leaning towards CBroe's first comment. Doing the AJAX call beforehand is more complex than what I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I believe the comment left by adeneo is correct - the onerror method does not contain the info I want, so what I would like is not going to work.  However, CBRoe's suggestion to deliver an alternative image got me thinking.

Warning! Ugly hack follows:

I am delivering different images depending on the "error message" the server would like to send.  They can be displayed, or as a hack, JavaScript can analyse the images.  A huge amount of data can be encoded as pixel data, but reading it is a pain.  Instead, for my limited number of error conditions, I am making sure that each image has a different width and/or height from each other and from valid images (for my application, valid images have a minimum height), so I can quickly determine which image was sent, and which error condition it signals.

I don't recommend this, but it is a quick fix for my situation.